# How to tigger onClick function of another component element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-component

I created one class base component and one functional component. There are three buttons inside the functional component and I called that component to my class based component.

The functional component:

```
function PanelButton(props){

  return (
    <div>
      <Button.Ripple
        color="success"
        type="submit"
        style={{margin:"5px", width:"110px"}}
      >
        Submit
      </Button.Ripple>
      <Button.Ripple
        color="primary"
        id="clearButton"
        type="button"
        style={{margin:"5px", width:"110px"}}
      >
        Clear
      </Button.Ripple>
      <Button.Ripple color="danger" type="button" style={{margin:"5px", width:"110px"}}>
        Close
      </Button.Ripple>
    </div>
  )
}
export default PanelButton;
```

The class base component, in which I imported the functional component into:

```
import PanelButton from '../../components/customzied/PanelButton';

class TicketNew extends React.Component{

  state = {
    alertOption:[],
  }

  clickClear = () => {
    console.log("ok");
  }

  render() {
    const rqst = this.state.rquirdSate;
    return (
      <Card>
        <Formik>
          { ({ errors, touched}) => ( 
          <div>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <CardHeader>
                <PanelButton />
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <Row />
              </CardBody>
            </Form>
          </div>
        )}
        </Formik>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}

export default TicketNew;
```

When I click the `button(id = "clearButton")` from functional component, I need to run the Click clear function in Class component.

Comment: Just pass the clickClear function from parent (component) to child (function) as a prop. Like `<PanelButton handleClick={clearClick}  (...)>`. Then invoke that passed function (callback) in the child, like `<Button.Ripple onClick={handleClick} (...)>`

Comment: oh yeh, I will try that. my pleasure

Comment: Oh, and you need o `bind` the callback in the class component. Take a look at Sabbirs' answer..

Comment: @HynekS arrow functions *already* have `this` of the class-based component bound, so another binding is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `onClick` callback handlers as props to `PanelButton` to attach to each button's `onClick` prop. Pass `clickClear` as callback for clear button.

PanelButton

```
function PanelButton(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <Button.Ripple
        color="primary"
        id="clearButton"
        type="button"
        style={{ margin: "5px", width: "110px" }}
        onClick={props.onClear} // <-- attach callback to button's onClick handler
      >
        Clear
      </Button.Ripple>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

TicketNew

```
class TicketNew extends React.Component {
  state = {
    alertOption: []
  };

  clickClear = () => {
    console.log("ok");
  };

  render() {
    const rqst = this.state.rquirdSate;
    return (
      <Card>
        <Formik>
          {({ errors, touched }) => (
            <div>
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <CardHeader>
                  <PanelButton onClear={this.clickClear}/> // <-- pass this.clickClear to onClear prop
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <Row></Row>
                </CardBody>
              </Form>
            </div>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `clickClear` function as props to the `PanelButton` component. The `PanelButton` code will look like the following,

```
function PanelButton(props){

    return(
       <div>
           <Button.Ripple color="success" type="submit" style={{margin:"5px", width:"110px"}}>
               Submit
           </Button.Ripple>
           <Button.Ripple color="primary" id="clearButton" onClick={props.onClickCallback} type="button"  style={{margin:"5px", width:"110px"}}>
               Clear
           </Button.Ripple>
           <Button.Ripple color="danger" type="button" style={{margin:"5px", width:"110px"}}>
               Close
           </Button.Ripple>
       </div>
   )
}
```

And the `TicketNew` code will look like this,

```
...
<CardHeader>
    <PanelButton onClickCallback={this.clickClear.bind(this)} />
</CardHeader>
...
```